# servlet pdf coming up as text in chrome

Tags: javascript, pdf, servlets

So I have a servlet whose URL is like blah.do?params=xyz

and in the servlet my code is similar to

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
request.setAttribute("Content-Type","application/pdf");
request.setAttribute("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=test.pdf");
byte[] bytes = SystemServer.getFileContents(fileId).getBytes();      
request.setAttribute("Content-Length","" + bytes.length);
out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
out.flush();
```

I use

```
window.open(url,"my file","someparams");
```

but chrome is opening the window as pure text and view source confirms that all that was outputted was

```
%PDF-1.4 %áéëÓ 2 0 obj  ..... all contents....%%EOF
```

So how can I force it to come up as a pdf

Whats wierd is I used identical code to get images back to the browser and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set those attributes on response object instead of request.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting several things as request attributes which should actually be set on the response.

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=test.pdf");
```